# PHP Google Maps API latitude and longitude

Tags: php, google-maps

How can I know the latitude and longitude number of my home to be displayed on the Google maps in my PHP contact page?

To be replaced on this coed segment:

```
 function initialize()   
   {  
      var mapOptions = {  
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(???????, ????????),  
      zoom: 10,   
      };
```

Comment: Try something on web where you can drag and drop marker, for example go here http://mondeca.com/index.php/en/any-place-en and try placing marker on your address, it will give you the lat lng for your home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you could do is look it up on Google Maps, and in the url you will find these numbers say for instance:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/New+York,+NY,+USA/@40.7058254,-74.1180861,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62!8m2!3d40.7127837!4d-74.0059413
```

You will notice the `@40.7058254,-74.1180861,11` in the url, this is what you will add in, minus the @.

Comment: Can you please tell me those two values for this URL: https://www.google.lk/maps/place/Kularatne+Rd,+Ambalangoda/@6.2422975,80.0603382,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3ae1819c7009d537:0xb0f7655ca6009970!8m2!3d6.2422975!4d80.0603382

Comment: @LenaStein - can't you read the `@6.2422975,80.060338‌​2` from your browser address bar? `https://www.google.lk/maps/place/Kularatne+Rd,+Ambalangoda/@6.2422975,80.0603382,17z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x3ae1819c7009d537:0xb0f7655ca6009970!2sKularatne+Rd,+Ambalangoda!3b1!8m2!3d6.2422975!4d80.0603382!3m4!1s0x3ae1819c7009d537:0xb0f7655ca6009970!8m2!3d6.2422975!4d80.0603382`

Comment: @Poria Sir, I used exactly these two values. But in my webpage show incorrect location? Why is that?

Comment: make sure you're only putting in the numeric values as `6.2422975,80.060338‌​2` and not `@6.2422975,80.060338‌​2`

Comment: @MarkBaker. Yes. Thanks a lot. Now I solved my problem.

Comment: @ConorThompson. Yes. Thanks. I removed @ and now it works fine. thanks